# What wattage heating element required for 500 degree Celsius oven temperature

Tags: heat, watts

i have 32 litres OTG oven which is of 2000 watts and can generate Max. 250 degree Celsius .

```
40 Litre capacity
2000 watts
```

OTG has 2 heating elements, one at top and one at bottom. so each heating element is of 1000 watts, when i am on broil mode only 1000 watts heating element is used which is upper heating element, so it takes a lot of time to cook food and i am planning replace it with high watt heating element.

replacing with this one

```
3000W 220V heating element.
```

ref: [heating element](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/3000W-220V-hand-shape-sauna-room-electric-heat-tube-5U-dry-oven-heating-element/32395724095.html?spm=2114.01020208.3.2.pDylJE&ws_ab_test=searchweb201556_6_79_78_77_80,searchweb201644_0,searchweb201560_9)

i am trying to achieve high temperature ~ 500 degree Celsius and quicker, as food i am trying to prepare needs faster high temperature.

i have few questions regarding the same .

1) Replacing current heating element with High wattage heating element, will it give me more temperature or same temperature but quicker ?

2) there is thermostat too on the OTG , which has max 250 degree Cesius reading and knob. 
Do i have change that too ?
or need to get the external thermometer.
i am only planning to use it for specific food preparation which needs high temperature.

3) whats is the relation in between watts and heat generated by heating element ?

- OTG outer body is pure stainless stell, so i dont think their will be any melting issue or something like that .

---

update:

i was under impression that majority ovens can go upto 500 degree celisus, after checking https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oven_temperatures , i have realized the 250-260 is the highest temperature i can get using oven.

i was trying to get same effect of the "Tandoori Clay Oven" here its says it can go up to 480 degree celsius. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tandoor

e.g.
[image: Tandoori Clay Oven]

after reading answers, i think its a bad idea to use current oven for high temperature like 500 degrees.

the above heating element manufacturer said the heating element can reach upto 200 degree celsius even though its 3000 watts.

so does this mean , it can reach 200 degree quicker ?

Comment: Hot enough to melt solder...

Comment: Are you sure you want to cook at 500° C? That's equivalent to 932° F. My oven max temperature is 500° F (not C) and I never need to cook anything at that temperature.

Comment: Autoignition temperature of Magnesium :)

Comment: This sounds like an excellent way to burn your house down.

Comment: OTG = Oven Toaster Grill?

Comment: @DaveX yes, oven toaster griller.

Comment: 500C would be incandescently glowing a dull red.  your stainless might not melt, but it could melt stuff on the other side of the stainless.  Your current coils in the oven are probably glow a bright cherry red of 800C to heat up the rest of the oven to ~250C  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incandescence for a rough color code.  The relationship between watts and temperature depends on how fast energy leaks out of the system.  If it heat can't escape as you keep putting watts in, the temperature will keep increasing until some sort of failure.

Comment: If your new element fails at 200C, it won't glow like normal oven elements, and will probably fail in an oven-like application.  If it is limited to 200C itself by some sort of thermostat in contact with the coil, it will take a long time to make the chamber approach 200C and will never get to 250C.

Comment: @DaveX i have checked my currrent coil doesnt glow up, idk may be thermostat is not letting it go to its full capacity. the coils are black/dark brown in color and the color stays as it is, even when fully hot.

Comment: It sounds like you want something like an electrically fired brick oven like https://www.pizzamaking.com/forum/index.php?topic=32855.0

Comment: @DaveX if i add high quality insulation inside OTG body , like glass wool, or those latest sheets, idk whats they called , but they are all over ebay, can i try 500 degree coil ? or is it still dangerous and clay is the only option ? i can fill my current OTG cavity with clay too  :)  thanks for your input , i really appreciate it.

Comment: The elements in my 1500W toaster oven glow bright red when I turn it on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32600/discussion-between-dave-x-and-amb).

Comment: https://www.crystec.com/kllmthe.htm
try this company, i put them in a woodfired pizza oven for Neapolitan pizza

Answer (score 3):

1) Both. It depends on how the internal circuitry is driving it, which leads to the answer to the second question

2) That thermostat will drive the heating element on and off in order to achieve the desired temperature. So it will only go up to 250C. You'll need to replace the thermostat (as well as related power cables - they likely won't be capable of handling 15A).

3) There is a fairly complex mathematical relationship between the wattage output and maximum heat. There's no simple way to determine this.

It's also worth mentioning that it may not even be *possible* to drive your oven to 500C, it's possible that more heat will escape than can be added in a given time unit above a certain temperature.

You will also need to consider all of the other implications of having something at 500C, including things like solder melting.

Comment: just received reply from the above posted heating element manufaturer and he says , the element can go to 200 degree celsius, even though its 3000W , how is this possible ? does it mean it can reach to 200 degree quicker ?

Comment: No, there's multiple meanings, but the most likely one is that the element itself will start to fail above 200C. It's possible that the element is designed to heat a large amount of material to around that temperature quickly.

Comment: One could immerse a 3000W heater in a water tank and it won't go above 200C (100C) as long as it remains immersed.  The energy would go into heating the water.  If the water isn't present, the temperature would rapidly increase unless it is taken away by some other method.    A 200C coil might be good for water heating but bad for a free-air oven application.

Answer (score 0):

Using the correct type of elements such as FeCrAl alloy (not sure what else might work at your considerably lower temperature - plain old nichrome probably would) electric kilns get to more than 1000C

But.

That is heavily affected by **how well insulated** they are (very) as well as using a heating element that can stand the heat (and those particular elements need to be kept in an oxidizing atmosphere since they are protected by an oxide coating in use, and degrade rapidly in a reducing atmosphere.)

Try not to burn your house down...